# How to change button class in a div while just the last one can keep the change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this code to change my buttons's class:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var btn=$(this);
    if(btn.attr('class')=='tct-button'){
        btn.removeClass('tct-button').addClass('tct-button2');
    }
    else{
        btn.removeClass('tct-button2').addClass('tct-button');
    }

});
```

The problem is that I have multiple div's with multiple buttons in each. I need to change this so that every time I click on a button in a div the others which were changed by a previous click (in that same div) change back to the default class which is 'tct-button', and just the last clicked button turns to 'tct-button2'. Would you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an additional class to your buttons (tct-button2) whilst keeping tct-button on every button you could do what Satpal suggested.

However, from the sounds of it and I may be wrong, if you want to change the classes so that each button only has one class at a time on it (either tct-button or tct-button2) you can do similar to what Satpal suggested and use:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.tct-button2').addClass('tct-button').removeClass('tct-button2'); //Add original class and Remove tct-button2 class
    $(this).removeClass('tct-button').addClass('tct-button2'); //Add the class to current element
});
```

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/xao46uzs/

to only affect buttons in the div the clicked one belongs to, use a similar method to:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('div').find('.tct-button2').addClass('tct-button').removeClass('tct-button2'); //Remove all class in that div
    $(this).removeClass('tct-button').addClass('tct-button2'); //Add the class to current element
});
```

(You might want to use a better selector for the parent, possibly a class or what ever your actual html uses)

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/xao46uzs/3/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I have multiple div and I need the change to happen in the div which the button belongs to. the code you both said is working but changes all the buttons in all the divs. for example, in your demo, if I click on a button in div Two, the one in div One is changing too.

Comment: Ah, ok. That wasn't initially clear from the question, sorry. Updated my answer to further suit your requirement.

Comment: thanks for the code, but why it just works in one of the divs and not the rest? (Oh Thanks I fixed it. Thank you so much)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, was this what you were after? My code, on click of a button looks for that buttons parent (in this case `div` then finds all buttons in that parent with the `tct-button2` class and then adds the original class to them and removes the `tct-button2` class from them (in effect resetting all buttons in there). Then it removes the original class for the clicked button and adds the new `tct-button2` class to it. Please let me know if there is any other requirement you are trying to achieve if this doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Your code was perfect, there was a stupid span in there :D I forgot to delete. Now it's working. Sorry I just started learning. this is my second day with Javascript.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Welcome to Javascript and JQuery :) Good luck with the learning.

Answer (score 2):

use **[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** in jquery ,there is no need to check hasClass()

```
$(this).toggleClass("tct-button2 tct-button");
```

### **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/59g7e7tf/)**

Comment: but this keeps the rest changed too. When I click on a button I need the other on go back to tct-button (the default class)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

> Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

*Code*

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var btn=$(this);
    if(btn.hasClass('tct-button')){
        btn.removeClass('tct-button').addClass('tct-button2');
    }
    else{
        btn.removeClass('tct-button2').addClass('tct-button');
    }       
});
```

However I think you need

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.tct-button2').removeClass('tct-button2'); //Remove all class 
    $(this).addClass('tct-button2'); //Add the class to current element
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this change all other tct-button2 in other div?I just need the change in the div the button belongs to.